# How to pass data from a model as data to a

Tags: c#, entity-framework, model-view-controller

I have two models Doctor and Patients.

I want to display Names of doctors in a dropdown/select in form for patients.

This is how my Patients Create View Looks like:

```
@model Application.Models.Patient
@model List<Application.Models.Doctor>
@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers

<link href="~/lib/twitter-bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="~/lib/jquery/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="~/lib/jquery-validate/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script src="~/lib/jquery-validation-unobtrusive/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js"></script>
<link href="~/css/StyleSheet.css" rel="stylesheet" />
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Create";
}
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <link href="~/lib/twitter-bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="sidebar">
            <nav class="nav flex-column">
                <a asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index" class="nav-item nav-link">Home</a>
                <a asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Create" class="nav-item nav-link">Add User</a>
                <a asp-controller="Home" asp-action="All" class="nav-item nav-link">All User</a>
            </nav>
        </div>
        <div class="area card">
            <div class="card-body" style="background-color: aqua">
                <form asp-action="Create" asp-controller="Patient" method="post">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label asp-for="Name">Patient Name</label>
                        <div>
                            <span asp-validation-for="Name" style="color: red;"></span>
                        </div>
                        <input asp-for="Name" class="form-control" type="text" id="Name" name="Name" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label asp-for="Adress">Address</label>
                        <div>
                            <span asp-validation-for="Adress" style="color: red;"></span>
                        </div>
                        <input asp-for="Adress" class="form-control" type="text" id="Adress" name="Adress" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label asp-for="BloodGroup">Blood Group</label>
                        <select asp-for="BloodGroup" class="custom-select">
                            <option selected>Custom Select Menu</option>
                            <option value="A+">A+</option>
                            <option value="A-">A-</option>
                            <option value="B+">B+</option>
                            <option value="B-">B-</option>
                            <option value="AB+">AB</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label asp-for="BloodGroup">Blood Group</label>
                        @{
                                                <select asp-for="BloodGroup" class="custom-select">
                                                    @foreach(var d in ViewBag.doc)
                                                    {
                                                    <option value="">@d.FirstName</option>
                                                    }
                                                </select>
                        }
                    </div>
                    <button class="btn btn-block btn-primary" type="submit">Submit</button>
                </form>

            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

i am not able to add two models in a single view. I get an warning "the 'model' directive may only occur once per document"

I tried passing, List of  Doctors in View as ViewBag but it din't help.

```
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult Create()
{
    ApplicationContext application = new ApplicationContext();
    List<Doctor> doctor = application.Doctor.ToList();
    ViewBag.Doc = doctor;
    return View();
}
```

What am i missing ? Please help me.

Comment: Why are you trying to pass the same model i.e. Application.Models.Patient twice in the view as specified by your first two lines of code? One as a list and another as normally?

Comment: Thanks for pointing out. I have edited the code. i am trying to pass two models- doctors and patients.

Comment: This is where the concept of ViewModel starts to play. You need a different class that has a Patient property and a List of Doctors as another property. Then you can have a single @model that is the ViewModel